# Applescript's 'move folder' issue

Tags: applescript

First of all, I do not understand why the `move folder` command does not remove the source on finish.

In an automation, I want to move folders. Since the `move folder` command does not remove the source, I have to add the `delete` command as well.
For some reason, however, if the size of the folder is like 3GB, the script returns with the 'The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error.' message.

I click 'ok' and `move folder` command finishes up, while the `delete` does NOT. Does anyone know why?

See below:

```
tell application "Finder"
    move f to dest
    delete f
end tell
```

FYI: The above code works fine when running on small folders (like 200Mb)

Comment: "I do not understand why the move folder command does not remove the source" -- Wild guess: you're moving files between volumes. That's just how Finder was designed to work.

Comment: Hmm. I should test your idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When done correctly, the folders you move, will be moved, you should not have to delete them afterwards, at least this is how it worked up to Mavericks.

```
 set desktopHFS to (path to desktop folder as text)
 tell application "Finder"
    set moveTarg to folder (desktopHFS & "MoveFolderTest")
    set moveDest to folder (desktopHFS & "Junk")
    move moveTarg to moveDest replacing no
 end tell
```

I have never tried to move folders of that size, and probably never will with AppleScript. I'd rather use the mv command of the shell. Apart from that, I **believe!** the reason it doesn't work, is that the initiating AppleEvent times out before Finder reports "all done" to your script.

I'd try something like this, and maybe add to the time, until the move operation can be done within the limits of it.

I also thought that move

```
 with timeout of 600 seconds -- 10 minutes, maybe you need more!
    try

        tell application "Finder"
            move f to dest
            delete f
        end tell
    on error e number n
        tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
            display alert "Error during move" & ":
" & e & " #: " & n
        end tell
    end try
 end timeout
```

Comment: I’m pretty sure you’re right about AppleScript timing out. The default timeout value isn’t enough for some larger folders and once that time value is exceeded, AppleScript will abort the operation with an error message.

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the late reply.
I tried it your way, but it did not work either.

Comment: Also, I know I should use something else for this.. I just needed something quickly.

Comment: Like foo said, it may be something about volumes: that you are moving from one volume to the other, the other thing that may kick in, is whether you have rights to delete on the volume. The move command itself, should delete the files itself, without any need of a following delete command. There are several unix tools that should be able to do what you want to accomplish, like mv, for instance, but I recommend you dry run it, some times first, on a thumb drive, with nothing more than test files that you can loose. Good Luck